# How to use 'Be invited'

Tags: tense

I'm here to ask you about using 'be invited'.

(Situation : A is asking about B's tomorrow schedule. )

A : Do you have any schedule tomorrow?

B : Yes I do.

1. **I've been invited** to the James' dinner party.
2. **I'm invited** to the James' dinner party.
3. **I was invited** to the James' dinner party.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native English-speaker I would use

> I've been invited to ...

I have been trying to think of *why*

> I'm invited to ...

doesn't seem quite right; haven't come up with a good reason.

I would use

> I was invited to ...

if the event was itself in the past or if I was invited but decided not to go.

> The James' had a party last week and I was invited.
>
> I was invited to the James' dinner party, but unfortunately I shall not be able to go as I am working in Manchester.